# Error while mounting directory from host via NFS

Tags: mount, virtualbox, nfs

I've been looking around the site but I couldn't find anyone with the same problem.
On VirtualBox, I have a machine with IP *.28 and another one with IP *.20.
The latter should mount a directory exported by the former.

*.28:/etc/exports

```
/myfolder *.20(rw,sync,no_root_squash,subtree_check)
```

*.20:/etc/fstab

```
*.28:/myfolder /myfolder nfs defaults 0 0
```

The recipient just does not mount the directory at startup.
When I try to manually mounting via:
    mount /myfolder

I get this error message:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on *.28:/myfolder,
missing codepage or helper program, or other error
(for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might
need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program)
```

Any idea why this happens?
(Or where I can get this "helper program" that I'm apparently missing?)

Comment: so it turns out I'm ACTUALLY missing mount.nfs, which should be part of nfs-common or some other package...does anyone know which one exactly?

Comment: Which distro are you running? That'd let us figure which package its in.

Comment: debian squeeze!

Comment: `nfs-common` is the package name. You can find these at http://www.debian.org/distrib/packages#search_contents or using `apt-file`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be sure I would start checking the basics:

- Can you ping the other machine? If not you're probably facing a network problem.
- Can you telnet the port nfs is using on the server? If not then maybe is a firewall issue or nfs misconfiguration.To see port info you can use the command (in the nfsserver):

  ```
  rpcinfo -p
  ```

If those things are right then try (from the nfs client):

```
   showmount -e *.28
```

You should see the /myfolder exported to whatever network * is. If not then there is a problem with the nfs server configuration.

PD: I think you should add the option **_netdev** to the *fstab* line so it does't try to do the mount till the network is ready. Anyway if manual mounting fails that's not the problem.

Comment: It does ping and there's no firewall. It appears that for some reason I was missing `/sbin/mount.nfs`.
I'm currently reinstalling the client's filesystem from scratch, taking care to include nfs-common, which should provide said `mount.nfs`. Thank you for your help!

Comment: reinstalling the entire OS seems like overkill.